# Add custom text not page for woocommerce checkout terms & conditions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a WordPress site running woocommerce and I have noticed wordpress code being pulled through onto the woocommerce checkout terms section this is due to woocommerce only allowing me to select a page and not give custom text for checkout terms & conditions.

Example of woocommerce checkout:
Terms and Conditions:
[vc_row][vc_column][vc_custom_heading text=”Terms & Condtions” font_container=”tag:h1|text_align:left” google_fonts=”font_family:Open%20Sans%3A300%2C300italic%2Cregular%2Citalic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic|font_style:400%20regular%3A400%3Anormal”][vc_column_text]

ETC ETC ETC ETC

Is there any hook I can use to edit the text another way? or would I just be easier to create a page with just the needed terms text?

Any help will be much appreciated. Kind Regards.

Comment: That code has some very odd doublequotes in it, are you using a word processor to edit code?

Comment: You need just to create a page with just the needed terms text of course…

Comment: @RiggsFolly This displayed text content tags is related to famous commercial [Visual composer plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431)…